# How to get repetition count in a junit 5 extension

Tags: java, junit5, junit5-extension-model

I try to write my own JUnit 5 extension, providing some simple information about test duration.
I also want to print out the repetition information but how can I access these informations in the extension?
Are there any simple ways instead of reflection or writing and parsing the numbers to the display name?

simple example:

```java
@ExtendWith(TimingExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass {
    @RepeatedTest(value = 5, name = "{currentRepetition}/{totalRepetitions}")
    public void myTest(TestInfo testInfo, RepetitionInfo repInfo) {
        // do some work here...
    }
}


public class TimingExtension implements AfterTestExecutionCallback {
    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if(context.getRequiredTestMethod().getDeclaredAnnotation(RepeatedTest.class) != null) {
            System.out.println("This was test X of Y"); // how to get currentRepetition and totalRepetitions here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no support for parameter injection in extensions. It's only one way. So in order to get `RepetitionInfo` in your `TimingExtension` you have to set it.

First you need to use `@RegisterExtension` e.g.

```
public class MyTestClass {

    @RegisterExtension
    TimingExtension timingExt = new TimingExtension();

    @RepeatedTest(value = 5, name = "{currentRepetition}/{totalRepetitions}")
    public void myTest(TestInfo testInfo, RepetitionInfo repInfo) {
        timingExt.setRepetitionInfo(repInfo);
        // do some work here...
    }
}

public class TimingExtension implements AfterTestExecutionCallback {

    private RepetitionInfo repInfo;

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if (context.getRequiredTestMethod().getDeclaredAnnotation(RepeatedTest.class) != null && repInfo != null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("This was test %d of %d", repInfo.getCurrentRepetition(), repInfo.getTotalRepetitions()))
            repInfo = null;
        }
    }

    public void setRepetitionInfo(RepetitionInfo repInfo) {
        this.repInfo = repInfo;

    }
}
```